# How does StackOverflow (and other sites) handle orphaned uploads?

Tags: http, file-upload, upload

I've been wrestling with a problem related to allowing users to upload files to my web server through a web page. How can I prevent uploaded files from being "orphaned" as a result of uploading and forgetting.

For example, when I create a question on StackOverflow, I have the option of adding an image to my question. This uploads the file and provides a URL to the resource on an SO server. What if I upload a file, but never submit my question (either I changed my mind, or my computer crashed, or I just closed the browser, etc...). Now there's a file on the SO server that isn't being used by anything. Over time, these could build up.

How can I handle this? Would some background process / automated task that performs checks for unused or expired files be sufficient? Maybe I'm over complicating this?

Comment: there's no "proper" way to deal with it. it comes down to policies. most people'd just say "you've got X time to finish this off, otherwise we'll clean up your mess and move on".

Comment: `"Would some background process / automated task that performs checks for unused or expired files be sufficient?"` - Generally, yes.  You can tweak how often that background process runs, what it does, etc.  But it's perfectly fine to have some off-line "clean up" tool which is actively trying to scrub bad data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for SO, but the way I've always done it is to run a scheduled task (e.g. cronjob) that goes through the database, looks for orphaned files that don't match entries in the uploads table, and whose creation date is older than 24 hours.

Secondly, having files upload to `/tmp` or `%temp%\` first and then copy over to a proper uploads directory does wonders for this kind of thing - a half finished upload can be left orphaned, and the OS will automagically clear it up when there are no longer any handles to it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've been using the `/temp` folder option to store files pending completion of a form.